# how to pull Line/Polygon by one of the points in kineticjs?

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

Some part of my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z4pSu/5/):

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: "canvas",
        width: 300,
        height: 200
    });

    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
    });
    var line = new Kinetic.Polygon({
        id: 'wall',
        points: [50, 50, 100, 50, 100, 100, 50, 100],
        stroke: "black",
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true
});
    line.on('dragmove', function(mouseEvent) {
        line.getPoints()[2] = {x:mouseEvent.x, y:mouseEvent.y};
        layer.draw();
});

stage.add(layer);

layer.add(line);
layer.draw();
```

​The task is to drag polygon by one of the corners (in example by right-bottom). But actually result is not that I expected. What is wrong in my code? or what is correct way of moving elemten by one of the points?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to only be able to drag by the corners of the shape, but not the sides? Is the changing of the vertices intended?

Right now you're setting the bottom right corner (line.getPoints()[2]) to the mouseEvent, which obviously would cause warping and little else.

Comment: Yes, I want to drag only one corner of the rectangle and other corners should be static and stay on initial places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this post [iOS6 pull/drag border on circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201983/kineticjs-ios6-pull-to-refresh-effect-on-a-circle)

The effects are similar, I think, to what you're looking for. You could animate the drag on any of your corners by detecting the click/touch location.

Let me know if you need another example.